# ggplot2: error message occurred when using scale_y_reverse() and scale_y_continuous() together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got an error message when I applied scale_y_reverse() and scale_y_continuous() together.

```
Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.
```

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

m <- matrix(runif(10000, 1, 100), nrow=10)
     ggplot(melt(m), aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill=value)) + 
     geom_tile() + coord_fixed(ratio=100) + scale_y_reverse()+
     scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
     scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

How can I reverse the y-axis and also remove the whtie padding?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (that is, use only one scale y):

```
 ggplot(melt(m), aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill=value)) + 
 geom_tile() + coord_fixed(ratio=100) + 
 scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0, 0))+
 scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```